# Clickable sub-menu that just appers on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a "sub-menu" that just appers on :hover. [[ **[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/tQcX9/)** ]]

```
$('.prices').hover(function () {
    $('.sub-menu').fadeIn(150);
}, function () {
    $('.sub-menu').fadeOut(120);
});
```

**Problem #1** ~ When I :hover the main menu and want to click on a sub-menu's link, it disappears.

**Problem #2** ~ When the first problem is solved, I will probably have another one: the sub-menu have a lot of links, so the intuitive user behavior (when he wants to go to the last link) is "draw" a triangle and go there, but this will do the sub-menu disappears again. How avoid this? (Illustration below)

[image]

**Please read**: I know that the sub-menu should be inside *li element*, but this do not work for what I am doing. The jsfiddle is just an example of the real stuff.

Comment: don't understand your second problem. How should it be related to a triangle here? why can the sub-menu disappear **again**?

Comment: @KingKing He's just trying to show that the distance the cursor has to travel is longer in the one marked in red. (Hypotenuses, hence the triangle reference)

Comment: @KingKing Just updated the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst in most cases I would suggest that you resolve your issues such that your sub-menu is an actual child of it's parent, if you really can't get around that, then something like this should work **([See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ianclark001/tQcX9/6/))**:

```
var priceTimeout;

function hide_prices() {
    clearTimeout(priceTimeout);
    $(".sub-menu").fadeOut(150);
}

$(".prices").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(".sub-menu").fadeIn(150);
});

$(".prices").on("mouseleave", function() {
    clearTimeout(priceTimeout);
    priceTimeout = setTimeout(hide_prices, 1000);
});

$(".sub-menu").on("mouseenter", function() {
    clearTimeout(priceTimeout);
});

$(".sub-menu").on("mouseleave", hide_prices);
```

A couple of things to note:

1. Because your `.sub-menu` is not a descendent of `.prices` then the `mouseleave` on prices will always fire when you move from one to the other. We get around this problem, and your "triangle" mouse movement problem by setting a timeout after which we clear the sub-menu. If we enter the sub-menu before that point, we clear our timeout so that it's never hidden.
2. You could shorten this code by using the short-hand `.hover()` as you were before, but I prefer the clarity of always using the explicit `.on()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because you add the `mouseout` event handler (the second argument in `hover`) which will hide the sub menu whenever it's triggered. There is a simple solution is to give a delay of about `100` ms before actually hiding the sub-menu, it's short enough to make no visual difference but it gives the hovering on the submenu a chance to stop the current animation of the submenu (which is `delay` and the consequent `fadeOut`). So the code should be added with:

```
// .prices:hover shows .submenu
$('.prices').hover(function () {
    $('.sub-menu').stop(true,true).fadeIn(150);
}, function () {
    $('.sub-menu').stop(true,true).delay(100).fadeOut(120);
});
//
$('.sub-menu').hover(function(){        
    $(this).stop(true);  
    $(this).fadeIn(0);
}, function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(120);
});
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/tQcX9/9/)

**NOTE**: Your second problem **should not be cared** too much. Normally, user should move the mouse over the submenu first. Otherwise we won't have any solution **unless** just let the submenu shown when the mouse is moved out of the Prices menu.

Comment: The use of `.stop()` works pretty well, but I think you should also be using it on the `.prices` hover section. Move your mouse in and out of the prices section and you'll see that you can just stack up a large animation queue otherwise.

Comment: @lan Clark thanks, fixed that issue, actually it is also the original problem of the OP's code.

Comment: TY :) - I think you should also increase the delay on the sub-menu fading out in order the achieve the "triangle" mouse movement effect the OP requested. Then it's a +1 from me :)

Comment: I think it's up to the OP, If it was me, I would never care about such a problem. The submenu should not be too long, maybe should have some scrollbar and also I think normally almost users (including me) will move the mouse over the submenu as quick as possible and scrolldown the menu.

Comment: "I would never care about such a problem", OK, but OP asked for the ability to be able to move from the menu straight to "year 2014" in his image, and that's not really possible in 120ms

Comment: @lan Clark in fact I think there is another problem if we increase the delay, that is it also increases the delay time before hiding the sub-menu when we move out of the Prices menu in **another way** (not cross the sub-menu). Anyway thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution, try this.

http://jsfiddle.net/iamrmin/tQcX9/3/

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="home">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="contact">
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="location">
        <a href="#">Location</a>
    </li>
    <li class="prices">
        <a href="#">Prices &raquo;</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Year 2005</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Year 2006</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Year 2007</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Year 2008</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Year 2009</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Year 2010</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Year 2011</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Year 2012</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Year 2013</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Year 2014</a>
    </li>
</ul>
    </li>
    <li class="jobs">
        <a href="#">Jobs</a>
    </li>
</ul>


.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    background: #F4F4F4;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px;
}


a
{
width: 101px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: How I said, I can't do this in my project (the jsfiddle is just an example) _and_ this do not solve Problem #2 (the intuitive user action).

Answer (score 0):

Since nesting the `ul`s doesn't work for you, here's an alternate solution.

Fade in the menu on hover event of `.prices`. But fade out only when mouse is left of `.sub-menu`. This would fix **both the problems**.

```
$('.prices').hover(function () {
    $('.sub-menu').fadeIn(150);
});
$('.sub-menu').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(150);
});
```

Also, you may want to hide the sub menu after a certain timeout period, if the user doesn't enter the `.sub-menu`.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tQcX9/5/)

Comment: Does not work because moving out of the `Prices` won't hide the sub-menu.

Comment: Yes, I understand. If I hid the sub-menu on moving out of prices, it wouldn't solve _Problem 2_.